# Using confirm_form to lead into a batch process

Tags: 7, forms

How can you use confirm_form from hook_menu and present the user with a Confirm action page, when clicked, goes and sets a Batch process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always do this with a simple submit handler on the form...works a treat:

```
function my_confirm_form($form, &$form_state) {
  return confirm_form($form, 'Are you sure you want to run this batch?');
}

function my_confirm_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $batch = my_batch_function();
  batch_set($batch);
}
```